# Publish subdirectory in another branch with git

Tags: git

I'm working on a little library, that only contains header files.
Additionaly I have written some tests and a CMakeLists.txt.
I have the following dir structure in my git master branch:

```
/
  include/
    header 1.hpp
    header 2.hpp
    ...
  tests/
    test 1.cpp
    test 2.cpp
    ...
  CMakeLists.txt
```

Now I want to use the library, but of course I dont need the tests or the CMakeLists.txt in my other project. So I want to put this structure in a branch called "devl" and in the master branch I only want the content of "include/".

I googled around but if some one else wants to extract a subdirectory they always want to put it into another repo.

So how can move the subdirectory into another branch? Or is it the wrong way publishing things?

Answer (score 0):

You could branch off a 'devl' branch and delete all tests and the CMakeLists.txt file.
Then when you have an update from the devl branch you could merge it back into master and delete any test files again.

To me that sounds cumbersome but doable.

Comment: Hmm ok, that was also my first idea but i thought it was not the way to do it, because it seemes to be to easy^^